# Vuetify Data Table Inline Filter

Tags: datatable, vuetify.js

Please see [this pretty Example by Dave Fontz on CodePen](https://codepen.io/fontzter/pen/qywQjK) on how to archive Date Table Inline Filter and to be able to customize how to display headers and tableData rows of a vuetify v-data-table.

This worked like acharm for me with vuetify version below 2.

However since upgrading to vuetify version 2 the

```
<template slot="headers" slot-scope="props">
```

and

```
<template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
```

inside

```
<v-data-table>
```

seem to be ignored.

Anyone any suggestion on how to migrate Daves solution to be compatible with vuetify version 2?

Any Help or Hint is much appreciated!

Complete Code by Dave also below.

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
      v-model="selected"
      :headers="headers"
      :items="filteredDesserts"
      :pagination.sync="pagination"
      select-all
      item-key="name"
      class="elevation-1"
    >
      <template slot="headers" slot-scope="props">
        <tr>
          <th>
            <v-checkbox
              :input-value="props.all"
              :indeterminate="props.indeterminate"
              primary
              hide-details
              @click.native="toggleAll"
            ></v-checkbox>
          </th>
          <th
            v-for="header in props.headers"
            :key="header.text"
            :class="['column sortable', pagination.descending ? 'desc' : 'asc', header.value === pagination.sortBy ? 'active' : '']"
            @click="changeSort(header.value)"
          >
            <v-icon small>arrow_upward</v-icon>
            {{ header.text }}
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="grey lighten-3">
          <th>
            <v-icon>filter_list</v-icon>
          </th>
          <th
            v-for="header in props.headers"
            :key="header.text"
          >
            <div v-if="filters.hasOwnProperty(header.value)">
              <v-select flat hide-details small multiple clearable :items="columnValueList(header.value)" v-model="filters[header.value]">

              </v-select>

            </div>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </template>
      <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
        <tr :active="props.selected" @click="props.selected = !props.selected">
          <td>
            <v-checkbox
              :input-value="props.selected"
              primary
              hide-details
            ></v-checkbox>
          </td>
          <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.calories }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.fat }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.carbs }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.protein }}</td>
          <td class="text-xs-right">{{ props.item.iron }}</td>
        </tr>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

JS:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    pagination: {
      sortBy: 'name'
    },
    selected: [],
    headers: [
      {
        text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
        align: 'left',
        value: 'name'
      },
      { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
      { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
      { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
      { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
      { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' }
    ],
    filters: {
      fat: [],
      carbs: [],
      iron: [],
    },
    desserts: [
      {
        value: false,
        name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
        calories: 159,
        fat: 6.0,
        carbs: 24,
        protein: 4.0,
        iron: '1%'
      },
      {
        value: false,
        name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
        calories: 237,
        fat: 9.0,
        carbs: 37,
        protein: 4.3,
        iron: '1%'
      },
      {
        value: false,
        name: 'Eclair',
        calories: 262,
        fat: 16.0,
        carbs: 23,
        protein: 6.0,
        iron: '7%'
      },
      {
        value: false,
        name: 'Cupcake',
        calories: 305,
        fat: 3.7,
        carbs: 67,
        protein: 4.3,
        iron: '8%'
      },
      {
        value: false,
        name: 'Gingerbread',
        calories: 356,
        fat: 16.0,
        carbs: 49,
        protein: 3.9,
        iron: '16%'
      },
      {
        value: false,
        name: 'Jelly bean',
        calories: 375,
        fat: 0.0,
        carbs: 94,
        protein: 0.0,
        iron: '0%'
      },
      {
        value: false,
        name: 'Lollipop',
        calories: 392,
        fat: 0.2,
        carbs: 98,
        protein: 0,
        iron: '2%'
      },
      {
        value: false,
        name: 'Honeycomb',
        calories: 408,
        fat: 3.2,
        carbs: 87,
        protein: 6.5,
        iron: '45%'
      },
      {
        value: false,
        name: 'Donut',
        calories: 452,
        fat: 25.0,
        carbs: 51,
        protein: 4.9,
        iron: '22%'
      },
      {
        value: false,
        name: 'KitKat',
        calories: 518,
        fat: 26.0,
        carbs: 65,
        protein: 7,
        iron: '6%'
      }
    ]
  }),
  computed: {
    filteredDesserts() {
      return this.desserts.filter(d => {
        return Object.keys(this.filters).every(f => {
          return this.filters[f].length < 1 || this.filters[f].includes(d[f])
        })
      })
    }
  },

  methods: {
    toggleAll () {
      if (this.selected.length) this.selected = []
      else this.selected = this.desserts.slice()
    },
    changeSort (column) {
      if (this.pagination.sortBy === column) {
        this.pagination.descending = !this.pagination.descending
      } else {
        this.pagination.sortBy = column
        this.pagination.descending = false
      }
    },
    columnValueList(val) {
      return this.desserts.map(d => d[val])
    }
  }
})
```

[See it in Action on CodePen](https://codepen.io/fontzter/pen/qywQjK)

Comment: You should avoid using arrow functions for 'data' -  because 'this' is set to global in array functions not to the vue instance. This may lead later to problems.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work in a later version of vuetify?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I made a pen that filters columns, it's not exactly what you asked for, but it might give you an idea. It uses custom filtering from vuetify 2 documentation

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <template>
      <div>
        <v-data-table
          dense
          :headers="headers"
          :items="desserts"
          item-key="name"
          class="elevation-1"
          :search="search"
        >
          <template v-slot:body.prepend>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <v-text-field v-model="search" type="text" label="Dessert name"></v-text-field>
              </td>
              <td>
                <v-text-field v-model="calories" type="number" label="Less than"></v-text-field>
              </td>
               <td>
                <v-text-field v-model="fat" type="number" label="Less than"></v-text-field>
              </td>
              <td>
                <v-text-field v-model="carbs" type="number" label="Less than"></v-text-field>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </template>
        </v-data-table>
      </div>
    </template>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

and JS:

```
  new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
      return {
        search: '',
        name: '',
        calories: '',
        fat:'',
        carbs:'',
        desserts: [
          {
            name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
            calories: 159,
            fat: 6.0,
            carbs: 24
          },
          {
            name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
            calories: 237,
            fat: 9.0,
            carbs: 37,

          },
          {
            name: 'Eclair',
            calories: 262,
            fat: 16.0,
            carbs: 23,

          },
          {
            name: 'Cupcake',
            calories: 305,
            fat: 3.7,
            carbs: 67,

          },
          {
            name: 'Gingerbread',
            calories: 356,
            fat: 16.0,
            carbs: 49,

          },
          {
            name: 'Jelly bean',
            calories: 375,
            fat: 0.0,
            carbs: 94,

          },
          {
            name: 'Lollipop',
            calories: 392,
            fat: 0.2,
            carbs: 98,

          },
          {
            name: 'Honeycomb',
            calories: 408,
            fat: 3.2,
            carbs: 87,

          },
          {
            name: 'Donut',
            calories: 452,
            fat: 25.0,
            carbs: 51,

          },
          {
            name: 'KitKat',
            calories: 518,
            fat: 26.0,
            carbs: 65,

          },
        ],
      }
    },
    computed: {
      headers () {
        return [
          {
            text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
            align: 'left',
            sortable: false,
            value: 'name',
            filter: value => {
              if (!this.name) return true
              return value < value
            }
          },
          {
            text: 'Calories',
            value: 'calories',
            filter: value => {
              if (!this.calories) return true
              return value < parseInt(this.calories)
            }
          },
          { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat',filter: value => {
              if (!this.fat) return true
              return value < parseInt(this.fat)
            }, },
          { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs',
          filter: value => {
              if (!this.carbs) return true
              return value < parseInt(this.carbs)
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
})
```

I made a pen [vuetify 2 data table column sort filter](https://codepen.io/rveruna/pen/gVBJmq)

Comment: how come this will work if headers are placed in computed instead of data? also, wondering if it is possible to do use the name filter in 2 columns and do an or instead of having to create another search property for the 2nd column

Comment: dont know pal, but try their support on discord, they are very helpful there with questions like that https://discord.com/invite/s93b7Fv

Comment: Beware, when you resize the view with the prepend options the datatable with lose its default css settings. Meaning that the view will be ugly